# Laravel 5.3 db:seed command simply doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, seeding, laravel-5.3, laravel-seeding

I do everything by-the-book:

1. Installed fresh Laravel 5.3.9 app (all my non-fresh apps produce the same error)
2. run `php artisan make:auth`
3. create migrations for a new table 
   `php artisan make:migration create_quotations_table --create=quotations

   ```
   Schema::create('quotations', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');

       $table->string('text');

       // my problem persists even with the below two columns commented out
       $table->integer('creator_id')->unsigned()->index('creator_id');
       $table->integer('updater_id')->unsigned()->index('updater_id');

       $table->softDeletes();
       $table->timestamps();
   });
   ```
4. Then I run `php artisan migrate`
5. Then I define a new seed `php artisan make:seeder QuotationsTableSeeder`

The complete content of the file, after I add a simple insert:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class QuotationsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    DB::table('quotations')->insert([
        'text' => str_random(10),

    ]);
}
}
```

6. Then I run `php artisan db:seed`

### problem

it simply doesn't work. No feedback presented, no errors in log file.
The probem persists in both my local environment (Win7, newest WAMP server)
and my Digital Ocean VPS powered by Ubuntu 16.04.
All the above steps I took in several separate apps - for no result. Also under Laragon 2.0.5 server.

### what I have tried

`php artisan optimize`  [as suggested here](http://laravel.io/forum/04-22-2015-cant-seed-db-in-laravel-5).

`composer dump-autoload` i `php artisan clear-compiled` also have brought no results

I also tried to seed just following the official docs example - failed.

I added `use DB;` to the seed file - still no result.

### to do

help!!! How come they don't work?

Comment: in my case when module in subfolders and want to run in directly without running other seeder php artisan db:seed --class=WM\Common\Seeder\SmsStatusSeeder

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Are you calling your seeder inside the `DatabaseSeeder` class? This way:

**database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(QuotationTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Or, add the `--class` option when using the `php artisan db:seed` command, this way:

```
php artisan db:seed --class="QuotationTableSeeder"
```

After creating or removing your seeders, don't forget to run the following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: for me it only works with the `--class` option, even when I added it to the public run function. Any ideas why?

Comment: Glad you answered this, first time the docs have lead me astray.

Comment: Glad I could help you.

Comment: You have to add the Seeder you created to DatabaseSeeder   `$this->call(QuotationTableSeeder::class);` after this, you can just call `php artisan db:seed`

Comment: It's 7.x and this is not in the official documentation.

Comment: why is this a step I need to take

Answer (score 0):

NB:
**Please use with caution on DEV ENVIRONMENT and/or DISPOSABLE DATABASES ONLY**

If anybody else is having issues with migrating AND seeding at the same time, please try

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Worked for me..

Comment: I will not recommend this since this command will: `drop all tables from the database and then execute the migrate command`. This can be catastrophic for some!

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
(mariaDB)
Check your auto commit.
mariaDB/data/my.ini <= here
Turn on your autocommit