# Laravel db:seed does not work without --class parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-seeding

Running `php artisan db:seed` does not work for some reason on my Laravel 5.6 project.

- The command runs (quietly) even without a database
- Does not return any error on the terminal

However, when I run `php artisan db:seed --class=ClassNameTableSeeder` it works. What could be the cause of such a weird behavior?

NB : Similar to questions like [39521913](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521913/laravel-5-3-dbseed-command-simply-doesnt-work) but not a duplicate.

Comment: can you show DatabaseSeeder class content?

Comment: Just confirming - Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`? sometimes I forget to do that

Comment: Does it throw an error? Can you add your `DatabaseSeeder` class to your question?

Comment: @PankajJha `composer dump-autoload` does not work.

Comment: @Davit `run` in default `DatabaseSeeder` is empty by default Marcin explains this in his answer. Thanks for you effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because by default `DatabaseSeeder` does nothing. Original code in fresh Laravel project looks like this:

```
public function run()
{
    // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
}
```

So to run any database seeder, you should uncomment this line and put valid class name, so for example:

```
$this->call(ClassNameTableSeeder1::class);
$this->call(ClassNameTableSeeder2::class);
```

and so on to run seeders for each class you put here.